# Don't understand why unpacking is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, unpack

Python unpacking not working

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
*m = a; //error

b,*m = a
print(m) //working
```

Please explain why the former one not working.

Comment: If `*m` worked it would just be copying the list and there is already syntax for that.

Comment: If you change the `*m = a; //error`, which syntactically incorrect because comments in Python start with `#`, to `*m = a  #error`, another syntax error occurs which explains the problem: `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`. You could just use `m = a[:]` to obtain a copy of all of `a` in this case.

Comment: @SuperShoot to be fair, though, there *are* multiple options for shallow copying a list, including: `m = a[:]`, `m = a.copy()`, `m = copy.copy(a)`, `m = list(a)`, `m = [x for x in a]` and, yes, `*m, = a`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Correct, and `*m` isn’t one of them.

Comment: @SuperShoot that's true, but wasn't your argument. That PEP introduced two new ways to shallow copy a list despite those that already existed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Read it as you like. My point was simply that `*m` is not valid syntax and if it were, its only function would be to copy the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), which introduced this *"extended iterable unpacking"* syntax, and the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), the "starred" target is only valid in an assignment where the target is an iterable.

> It is also an error to use the starred expression as a lone assignment
>   target, as in
>
> ```
> *a = range(5)
> ```
>
> This, however, is valid syntax:
>
> ```
> *a, = range(5)
> ```

So to make that syntactically valid, you could do:

```
*m, = a
```

or even:

```
[*m] = a
```

Note, though, that the idiomatic way to create a shallow copy of a list is with a slice:

```
m = a[:]
```

Comment: *a, = range(5) what does comma here ?

Comment: @user9580899 it makes it an assignment to an iterable target list, in which a starred target is valid syntax.

Comment: In general, a trailing comma after an expression turns it into a tuple. Without the star it would be a one-element tuple and the unpacking would fail.

Comment: @DanielH true, `m, = a` or `[m] = a` would only succeed when `len(a) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
*m = a
```

will throw a Syntax Error because you are trying to use the starred expression as a lone assignment target. You can either use `*m, = a`, `[*m] = a` or `(*m,) = a` to fix this.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b,*m = a
print(m)
```

This will work. Printing b will return 1 and m will return the list [2, 3, 4].