# why we cannot use alone starred target while assignment in python

Tags: python

I was going through the python docs on simple assignment.

I found below from the docs.

> Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in
> parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows.
>
> If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma,
> optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.
>
> Else:
>
> If the target list contains one target prefixed with an asterisk,
> called a “starred” target: The object must be an iterable with at
> least as many items as there are targets in the target list, minus
> one. The first items of the iterable are assigned, from left to right,
> to the targets before the starred target. The final items of the
> iterable are assigned to the targets after the starred target. A list
> of the remaining items in the iterable is then assigned to the starred
> target (the list can be empty).
>
> Else: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as
> there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from
> left to right, to the corresponding targets.

What I understood is that if the target list contains starred target then object, on RHS, must be iterable. So while assignment, python first unpacks the object and assigns the items as per the above rule and then rest of  the values is assigned to the starred target.

Now, Considering above I have kept only starred target and was expecting the values on RHS ( which is a tuple) to be assigned to starred target. However, Python  gives syntax error for this  line. I am still trying to understand where I am lacking as it is nowhere mentioned that I can't use starred target alone.

```
*a=1,2,3
```

But Below works. Please explain why here alone why alone starred target is working here ?

```
[*a] = 1,2,3
```

Comment: Probably because `*a=…` makes little sense and is probably a potential bug, as it has the same result as just `a=…`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't understand why unpacking is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322570/dont-understand-why-unpacking-is-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: you can do `*a, = 1, 2, 3`. Comma isn't typo. With list: `[a] == [a, ]` would be `True`. But `a != (a, )`

Comment: what is the difference between `*a=...`, `[*a]=...` and `*a,=...`  in terms of sementics ?

Comment: @deceze `*a=...` would not have the same result as just `a=...` if it were allowed because `*a=...` as an unpacking assignment would actually exhaust the iterable on the right and assign the generated items to `a` as a new list, whereas `a=...` is simply giving the reference on the right a name `a`.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, there are asterisks to this statement I didn’t all want to pack into my comment. Perhaps it’s better to say that if you wrote `*a=…`, you probably meant and should better write something like `a=list(…)`.

Comment: Please don't abuse backticks for emphasis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instead add a comma to make the unpacking assignment to an explicit tuple:

```
*a, = 1, 2, 3
```

as pointed out in [PEP-3132](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/):

> It is also an error to use the starred expression as a lone assignment
> target, as in
>
> ```
> *a = range(5)
> ```
>
> This, however, is valid syntax:
>
> ```
> *a, = range(5)
> ```

It is also pointed out in the same documentation that unpacking assignment to a list is semantically equivalent to unpacking assignment to a tuple:

> For example, if `seq` is a sliceable sequence, all the following
> assignments are equivalent if `seq` has at least two elements:
>
> ```
> a, b, c = seq[0], list(seq[1:-1]), seq[-1]
> a, *b, c = seq
> [a, *b, c] = seq
> ```

You can also refer to the [discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007211.html) with Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, from the Python mailing list, for how the decision to disallow `*a = range(5)` was made:

> > > Also, what should this do? Perhaps the grammar could disallow it?
> > >
> > > ```
> > > *a = range(5)
> > > ```
> >
> > I say disallow it.  That is ambiguous as to what your intentions are even if
> > you know what `'*'` does for multiple assignment.
>
> My real point was that the PEP lacks precision here. It should list
> the exact proposed changes to Grammar/Grammar.
>
> --
> --Guido van Rossum (home page: [http://www.python.org/~guido/](http://www.python.org/%7Eguido/))

as well as this follow-up [discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007243.html):

> > > Also, what should this do? Perhaps the grammar could disallow it?
> > >
> > > ```
> > > *a = range(5)
> > > ```
> >
> > I'm not so sure about the grammar, I'm currently catching it in the AST
> > generation stage.
>
> Hopefully it's possible to only allow this if there's at least one
> comma?
>
> In any case the grammar will probably end up accepting `*a` in lots of
> places where it isn't really allowed and you'll have to fix all of
> those. That sounds messy; only allowing `*a` at the end seems a bit
> more manageable. But I'll hold off until I can shoot holes in your
> implementation. ;-)
>
> --
> --Guido van Rossum (home page: [http://www.python.org/~guido/](http://www.python.org/%7Eguido/))

Comment: How `*a = range(5)` is ambiguous`?

Comment: I personally don't think it's ambiguous, but as shown above the developers who were making the decision thought it's ambiguous and made the decision to disallow it.

Comment: It's interesting that *\*a, = range(N)* is functionally equivalent to *a = tuple(range(N))* so I wonder if one is in any way "better" than the other

Comment: Actually `*a, = range(N)` produces `a` as a *list*, not a tuple, so it's functionally equivalent to `a = list(range(N))`. The former is more concise, while the latter is more readable. No definitive "better" here.

Comment: @blhsing , Thanks for the comment. So does it mean that `*a=...` is explicitly is not allowed though this is grammatically correct .

Comment: You're welcome. As shown in the discussion above the developers made an extra effort to specifically disallow `*a=...` from being part of the Python grammar so no it is not gramatically correct.

Comment: @blhsing I stand corrected. Definitely doesn't create a tuple. In my opinion, FWIW, the unpacking syntax (in this scenario) is obscure to most developers and should probably be avoided for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, `*a=1,2,3` will throw a syntax error because you are trying to use the starred expression as a lone assignment target. `[*a] = 1,2,3` works just as `(*a,)=1,2,3` or simply add a trailing comma after your starred expression like this `*a, = 1, 2, 3` They all return a list of the values i.e. [1,2,3].